# DynamoDB CreateTableRequest and setAttributeDefinitions

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm just starting out with DynamoDB and the Java SDK.

One thing I'm not getting is why the CreateTableRequest object (request) is wanting attribute definitions?

What is not making sense is that a Dynamo table is schemaless, but it's asking me for attribute definitions.

Or is this an indexing thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "mostly" schemaless, but you still need to provide a hash key (and optionally a range key) that remain fixed for the lifetime of the table; you'll also need to provide the provisioned read and write throughput.

Comment: So setAttributeDefinitions() is all about these indexing hints?

Comment: Yup, plus you can think of the key as being the canonical name for the objects in the table - if you assign a new object to that key then you overwrite the old object.  For any non-key attribute it doesn't matter if two objects have the same value for the attribute, but the table needs at least one key attribute in order to make it possible to add/update/remove objects.